# Error when upgrading goaop/framework module from v2.3.5 to v3.0.0

Tags: php, module, composer-php, runtime-error, goaop

Recently I updated my goaop/framework composer module from v2.3.5 to v3.0.0, while taking note of the breaking changes on their ChangeLog, I came to experience an error that doesn't seem to relate to any of the breaking changes mentioned.
Here's the exact error which comes up:

`PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Typed property Go\Aop\Framework\AbstractInterceptor::$adviceOrder must not be accessed before initialization in /var/www/html/app/vendor/goaop/framework/src/Aop/Framework/AbstractInterceptor.php:119 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/app/vendor/goaop/framework/src/Aop/Framework/AbstractJoinpoint.php(95): Go\Aop\Framework\AbstractInterceptor->getAdviceOrder() #1 [internal function]: Go\Aop\Framework\AbstractJoinpoint::Go\Aop\Framework\{closure}() #2 /var/www/html/app/vendor/goaop/framework/src/Aop/Framework/AbstractJoinpoint.php(100): uasort() #3 /var/www/html/app/vendor/goaop/framework/src/Aop/Framework/AbstractJoinpoint.php(116): Go\Aop\Framework\AbstractJoinpoint::sortAdvices() #4 /var/www/html/app/vendor/goaop/framework/src/Instrument/Transformer/WeavingTransformer.php(142): Go\Aop\Framework\AbstractJoinpoint::flatAndSortAdvices() #5 /var/www/html/app/vendor/goaop/framework/src/Instrument/Transformer/WeavingTransformer.php(106): Go\Instrument\Transforme`

I took a look at their ChangeLog and sorted out their documented breaking changes https://github.com/goaop/framework/blob/3.0.0/CHANGELOG.md

**Breaking Changes:**

- [BC BREAK] Switched to the PHP7.2 and upper, strict types, return type hints and new syntax
- [BC BREAK] Removed the Joinpoint->getThis() method, as not all
  joinpoints belongs to classes (eg. FunctionInvocation)
- [BC BREAK] Removed the Joinpoint->getStaticPart() method as it can return anything, better to use explicit methods

Could there be another breaking change that isn't yet accounted for, if so can this be resolved?

Comment: Please share more details. How is this problem related to Composer? What did you try to resolve it?

Comment: Hi @NicoHaase the problem arose when I upgraded the module using composer. Based on the breaking changes which I shared from CHANGELOG.md, none of them conflicted with this error.

Comment: For example one of the breaking changes was [BC BREAK] Removed the Joinpoint->getThis() method, as not all joinpoints belongs to classes (eg. FunctionInvocation). So I was required to replace these invocations from this $invocation->getThis(); to $invocation;